# Where did it go? used tar in cygwin without a target .tar file

Tags: cygwin

Riddle me this Sasquatch - I am using Cygwin 3.6.0 on Windows 7.  I just moronically ran the following command:

```
tar cvfz dir1/dir2/dir3/*
```

(you will note the missing target file ***i_am_a_moron.tar.gz*** in the command) and it happily traipsed through all 713 files without the slightest complaint.

It took me a minute or so to realize what I had done.  I wouldn't be too concerned if I had not been doing this to package up and relocate bunches of files (images) to save space on a drive - because the drive now tells me there is less space than when I began the tar.

**Where in the drive did that bugger go (if at all)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Manual

```
Examples:
  tar -cf archive.tar foo bar  # Create archive.tar from files foo and bar.
```

So it overwrote the first file of `dir1/dir2/dir3/*` expansion.

Try `file dir1/dir2/dir3/*`

eg:

```
$ tar -czf prova/*

$ file prova/*
prova/prova.c:   gzip compressed data, last modified: Fri Feb  2 14:13:10 2018, from Unix
prova/prova.cc:  C source, ASCII text
prova/prova.f:   ASCII text
prova/prova.sh:  Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
prova/prova.txt: empty
```